# Android MapView Controls for changing to Satellite view

Tags: android, android-mapview

How do I add the built-in buttons for switching between Satellite and and Traffic view.

I can add my own buttons and call the  setSatellite(boolean), setTraffic(boolean) methods, but I was hoping there are built in buttons to do that like the Zoom buttons.